# adding a back button for dynamically injected pages with Jquery Mobile & phonegap

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

Has anyone successfully implemented a back button for dynamically injected pages with Jquery Mobile & phonegap

I am trying to add a back button to move back inside dynamically injected pages, when I add

```html
<div id="dataview" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header" data-backbtn="true">
        <h1></h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content"></div>
</div>
```

The app goes back to the first loaded div instead of the previous loaded div i.e it goes home instead of -1

Comment: Managed to add the back button, had to change the structure of my pages though.

Comment: Also managed to listen for the phone back button to customize how it behaves to prevent erratic back navigation page loads.
    function onBackKeyDown(){
        history.back();
        
    }